# snowflake kafka connector : Not able to select a table, even not able to access the row count of table

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

[image]I have created a table, but I am not to select the table and neither I am able to do the count(*) the table. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
Use role <rolename - role which created the table> ;
Select count(*) from <table_name>;
```

Check if the ownership still remains with the role that created the table/The role used has SELECT privileges on the table.

Comment: The TABLE was created with the help of SYSADMIN, but later the ownership was provided to the kafka_connector_role_1. As the owner is now the role kafka_connector_role_1. So, please help as the table is too huge in size almost 27GB. Adding the image of the future grants given to the SCHEMA

Comment: As you said even tried with the ROLE SYSADMIN and even with ACCOUNTADMIN as I am getting error: SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on table 'UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021'

Comment: What role owns the database and schema?  And for your kafka role, was that role granted to sysadmin (which is a best practice)?  The kafka role likely needs usage grants on both the database and the schema in order to see the table.

Answer (score 0):

grants on UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021 show that it is owned by role KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1.

If you are running as SYSADMIN or ACCOUNTADMIN, make sure the KAFKA role is granted to one of the upper roles.

```
user role SYSADMIN;
grant role KAFKA_CONNECTOR_ROLE_1 to role SYSADMIN;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UAT_PRODUCT_TOPIC_15DEC2021;
```